# Why 2nd console not priniting?

Tags: javascript

```
let func=(a,b)=>{
  console.log(a+b)
}

let funci2=func=>(a,b)=>{
  console.log('2nd console')
  func(a+b)
}

let a =3
let b=5

funci2(func(a,b))
```

Came up with problem while programming. I know it's going to be something very childish.
In JS, why 2nd console is not printing? Output is just 8.

Comment: You want `funci2(func)(a,b);`

Comment: @Bergi why it returns " 2nd console NaN " now?

Comment: Try replacing `console.log(a+b)` by `console.log(a, b)` and you'll see why `a+b` is `NaN` in there.

Answer (score 0):

`funci2` takes one parameter and returns an arrow function. You do not call that function, so the `console.log` statement inside is not executed.